# Route 2 sibling components in 2 router-outlets

Tags: angular

So, I have `parent.component.html` :

```
  <router-outlet name="search"></router-outlet>
<addButton-component></addButton-component>
  <router-outlet name="table-router"></router-outlet>
```

`parent-routing.module.ts`:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { DataBrowserComponent } from './data-browser.component';
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', component: DataBrowserComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        loadChildren: () => import('./../table/table.module').then(m => m.TableModule),
        outlet: "table-router"
      },
      {
        path: '',
        loadChildren: () => import('./../search/search.module').then(m => m.SearchModule),
        outlet:"search"
      },]
  },

];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class ParentRoutingModule { }
```

`search-routing.module`:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { SearchComponent } from './search.component';
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: ':pathModel', component: SearchComponent },

];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class SearchRoutingModule { }
```

`table-routing.module`:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { TableComponent } from './table.component';
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: ':pathModel', component: TableComponent },
  
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class TableRoutingModule { }
```

My plan is to when I click in navbar (which is outside of this parent component), I send some `pathModel` to both `search` and `table` components, and render them, and when I click on `submit` in `search-component` to send model to `table-component` and rerender it.
Problem is that I do not get rendered anything in this router-outlets, and in console I don't have any error.

Comment: You have not shared the actual problem?

Comment: I did, my components does not render. If you need some other files tell me

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the below line

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', component: DataBrowserComponent, // <- problem here should be ParentComponent istead of DataBrowserComponent
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        loadChildren: () => import('./../table/table.module').then(m => m.TableModule),
        outlet: "table-router"
      },
      {
        path: '',
        loadChildren: () => import('./../search/search.module').then(m => m.SearchModule),
        outlet:"search"
      },]
  },

];
```

Because you are having the router outlet in the `parent.component.html` and not on the `data-browser.component.html`.